# PHP Parse details of uploaded files to another function on Form Submit in Laravel 5

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5, dropzone.js

I'm working on an Application in the Laravel 5 framework which requires multiple images to be uploaded. For this, I have a form which with a file input (I researched and came across dropzone.js so I'm using this like this)

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputAccName">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="inputAccName" class="form-control" id="inputAccName" required="true" value="{{ Auth::user()->name }}">
      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
   </div>
   <div class="dropzone" id="dropzoneFileUpload">
   </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      var baseUrl = "{{ url('/') }}";
      var token = "{{ Session::getToken() }}";
      Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
       var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#dropzoneFileUpload", { 
           url: baseUrl+"/user/uploadFiles",
           params: {
              _token: token
            }
       });
       Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
          paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
          maxFilesize: 2, // MB
          addRemoveLinks: true,
          accept: function(file, done) {

          },
        };
   </script>
   <input class="btn btn-success btn-lg" type="submit" name="formPassword" value="Save Changes">
</form>
```

So the user will input the name and upload up to 4 pictures (minimum 1 required).

I have a POST route which calls a function called "UpdateUserX" this function updates the user name in the database when the form is submitted.

In a separate function I have added the following code for the files upload:

```
public function uploadFiles()
{

    $destinationPath = 'uploads'; // upload path
    $extension = Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting file extension
    $fileName = rand(11111, 99999) . '.' . $extension; // renaming image
    $upload_success = Input::file('file')->move($destinationPath, $fileName); // uploading file to given path

    if ($upload_success) {
        return Response::json('success', 200); 

    } else {
        return Response::json('error', 400);
    }

}
```

This function is called by dropzone when images are uploaded. What I want to do from here is parse the details of uploaded images to the UpdateUserX function so i can store the details of the images in the database. Any advice in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Updated my question - I got the uploading to work but what I want to do from here is parse the details of uploaded files to the UpdateUserX function which is called when I submit the form with the user details so I can store the details of the images in the database also.

Comment: Deleting my answer since you changed the question. I don't know the answer to your new question.

Comment: You have to store some information about the uploaded images in your `uploadFiles` method, so you can identify them later.

Comment: @peaceman I'm going to try this with sessions.

Comment: I wasn't able to do this with Dropzone.JS as I couldn't implement it to use an existing form. That way, it could have uploaded through the form and i could have captured it in my controller function. Instead, I have used a default input with the file type. If anyone has tips on how I can upload on form submit with Dropzone or the following plugin: https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput it would be appreciated if you can put me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incase anyone is looking to do something similar. I wasn't able to do this with Dropzone.JS as I couldn't implement it to use an existing form. That way, it could have uploaded through the form and i could have captured it in my controller function. Instead, I have used a default input with the file type:

```
<input id="file" type="file" name="file[]" multiple="true">
```

Then i simply capture in my UpdateUserX function:

```
$files = Input::file('file');
$file_count = count($files);
// start count how many uploaded
$uploadcount = 0;
foreach($files as $file) {
  $rules = array('file' => 'required'); //'required|mimes:png,gif,jpeg,txt,pdf,doc'
  $validator = Validator::make(array('file'=> $file), $rules);
  if($validator->passes()){
    $destinationPath = 'uploads';
    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $upload_success = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
    $uploadcount ++;
  }
}
```

I will update my answer if in the future i find a way to do this with Dropzone or with the Bootstrap file input plugin: https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput

**UPDATE**

I found the following plugin which styles the file input: http://markusslima.github.io/bootstrap-filestyle/#Getstart I am now using this instead of Dropzone.JS with the above code.

Via JavaScript:

```
$(":file").filestyle({input: false});
```

Via data attributes:

```
<input type="file" class="filestyle" data-input="false">
```